# Moving Docker container to another computer/OS and load it there

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-14.04, dockerfile

Earlier I was Running Docker on Ubuntu 14.04 but due to some reason I am not able to boot into that OS  but then I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 in second partition. now I am having access to Ubuntu 14.04 data from new OS(16.04)

I was having  container(serene_jackson) running in older os with some data&code.

Now that I want to copy/run those container on Ubuntu 16.04 how can I do that

Where can I find docker container in older OS (14.04) files?
How do I copy those to new OS 16.04 so that data and code will not get lost?
How to run it in new system(if needs some non standard procedure )

Comment: Is docker version same on new OS?

Comment: I am not sure about this but Most probably yes as I used same documentation for both installation

Comment: I copied /var/lib/docker directory from Ubuntu 14.04 partition  into Ubuntu 16.04 partition  now to load it

Comment: Does this mean it is accessible now? If not and if you are copying the entire /var/lib/docker directory to new root file system, make sure you have stopped the docker service before doing that. Also, there is no guarantee that this method will work all the time as docker versions may be different on old and new operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

OK hey I solved this Problem.

> COPYING DOCKER CONTAIINER TO NEW OS

cd to home

```
cd ~
```

Docker stores containers in */var/lib/docker* directory

I copied  */var/lib/docker* directory  from Ubuntu14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop/docker

```
cp -r /media/user/66810500-0b65-4c96-bc14-9dd78033e1b/var/lib/docker /Desktop/docker
```

-r flag is important to copy subfolder(copy recursively )

*some time permission issue can occur in that case  change docker folder permission/group*

> IN UBUNTU 14.04

Then I tried to change default location entry in /etc/docker/daemon.json 
which should be pointing to */var/lib/docker*  to *Desktop/docker*. (as Suggested by my friend). But I didn't find /etc/docker/daemon.json. there

So I took backup of existing */var/lib/docker* directory for safety

```
mv /var/lib/docker /var/lib/docker_old
```

and replaced  */var/lib/docker* with  */Desktop/docker*

```
cp -r /Desktop/docker /var/lib/docker
```

And Restarted Docker service

```
sudo service docker restart
```

then when I did

```
sudo docker ps -a
```

I was able to see my old docker containers and thats what I needed